# How to fix cp issue during build with ninja?

Tags: android, makefile, build, recovery, ninja

I am currently compiling a custom recovery for an android phone. Sources are synced, device tree etc. all set up correctly. Now I am facing a rather banal-looking error during build. cp refuses to copy a directory, because -r is not specified in the build file.

I obviously tried to find the build file (rw_recovery/out/build_omni_daisy.ninja) and add the -r argument, but it seems to be regenerated at the beginning of every build process, as the process still fails and the previously changed line appears unchanged when opening the file after the attempted build.

These are the build steps:

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch omni_daisy-eng #config for the device
mka bootimage #device uses boot.img as recovery
```

This command leaves me with the following error:

```
[ 99% 6883/6884] Prebuilt (rw_recovery/out/target/product/daisy/kernel)
FAILED: rw_recovery/out/target/product/daisy/kernel
/bin/bash -c "(rm -f /home/luca/rw_recovery/out/target/product/daisy/kernel) && (cp rw_recovery/out/target/product/daisy/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/arch/arm64/boot/ rw_recovery/out/target/product/daisy/kernel )"
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'rw_recovery/out/target/product/daisy/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/arch/arm64/boot/'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
17:13:06 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

I would love to hear any suggestions about how to force ninja to execute the command with -r. Alternatively, suggestions about where to find the file from which the above mentioned build file is recreated after executing mka command are much welcomed as well.